# MIPS switching cases of strings?

Tags: mips

I have a project I've been working on. Basically I am supposed to take in a string and switch all uppercase letters to lowercase, and lowercase to uppercase. The problem with my project is that it is taking my punctuation's ASCII values and adding/subtracting 32 from it as well. How do I prevent my punctuation from being changed?

```
data
prompt: .asciiz "\n\nEnter an string of characters: "
result: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the string you entered: "
after_sort: .asciiz "\n\nHere is the string after the case sorting: "
buffer: .space 80
.text

main:

#Prints the prompt string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt 
syscall 

#reads string from user and saves in $a0
li $v0, 8
la $a0, buffer
li $a1, 80
syscall

#Prints the result string
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, result 
syscall

#Prints the string entered by the user
la $a0, buffer 
li $v0, 4
syscall


li $t0, 0 # t0 = i = 0
for_loop:
slti $t1, $t0, 80 # t1 = 1 if and only if t0 < 80
beq $t1, $0, for_loop_done

lb $t4, 0($a0)
beqz $t4, for_loop_done
beq $t4, 10, for_loop_done
slti $t2, $t4, 91
li $t3, 1
beq $t2, $t3, upper #if the character value is less than 91 branch to upper      addition
bne $t2, $t3, lower

upper:
addi $t4, $t4, 32 #adds 32 to the character value to lowercase it
j done

lower:
addi $t4, $t4, -32 #subtracts 32 from the character value to capitalize it
done:

addi $t0, $t0, 1

sb $t4, 0($a0)
addi $a0, $a0, 1

j for_loop
for_loop_done:

#Prints the result string
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, after_sort 
syscall

#Prints the string entered by the user
la $a0, buffer 
li $v0, 4
syscall

exitProgram:    li $v0, 10  # system call to
syscall         # terminate program
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you only have the check `if ($t4 <= 'Z')`. What you need to check is `if (($t4 >= 'A' && $t4 <= 'Z') || ($t4 >= 'a' && $t4 <= 'z'))`:

```
slti $t2, $t4, 91
beqz $t2, maybe_lower    # > 'Z', might be a lowercase letter
slti $t2, $t4, 65
beqz $t2, switch_case    # not < 'A', i.e. >= 'A' AND <= 'Z' , goto switch_case
j done

maybe_lower:
slti $t2, $t4, 97
bne $t2, $zero, done     # > 'Z' but < 'a', we're done
slti $t2, $t4, 123
beqz $t2, done           # > 'z', we're done

switch_case:
xori $t4, $t4, 0x20      # inverts bit 5, since that's what differs between upper and lowercase letters

done:
```

Comment: So in this case, does 'maybe_lower' replace the existing 'lower' label? If so, could you explain the step logic a little more? I'm thankful for the solution, but I want to understand it so that I can apply the logic myself

Comment: If `$t4 > 'Z'` then the character isn't an upper case letter. It might still be a lower case letter, so we jump to `maybe_lower` where we perform the check `$t4 >= 'a' && $t4 <= 'z'`.